# Are there negative effects of cancel-init Firestore Stream function?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

i have the following function

```
StreamSubscription? testStrream;
      testStrream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test').limit(1)
          .orderBy('count',descending: true)
          .snapshots().listen((event) {
        for(var element in event.docs){
          log.log(element.get('count').toString());
        }
      });
```

The previous function is turned off and on continuously by the user using `testStrream.cancel()`

in other world There is little time between on and off ..
1- on
2- 2 sec or 3 .. etc
3- `testStrream.cancel()`

question : Is it recommended that there be a specific time between om-off the stream ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no inherent drawbacks to using `StreamSubscription.cancel()` to end a Firestore stream. But, turning the stream on and off frequently will generate extra network requests and slow down your program. It is normally advised to only turn on the stream when absolutely necessary and to shut it off when no longer required. If you need to toggle the stream frequently, you can think about putting a debouncing system in place to reduce the number of network requests.

Reference:
[Best practices for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#reduce-the-number-of-reads)

Comment: . If you need to toggle the stream frequently, you can think about putting a debouncing system in place to reduce the number of network requests.
......................
can you please explain more about that .. i did not find more info of this part in your link

Comment: Debouncing is a method for controlling how many times a certain function is called in a given amount of time. When a user toggles a Firestore stream frequently, debouncing can be used to save needless network queries by waiting a predetermined period of time after the previous toggle before making the request.